# Environment info in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I've been trying to use Tornado for some part of my application. For that, I want to find out the environment information of the user, that is, the browser and OS of the user.

In pylons, I can do that but I am not getting how to do that in Tornado/

Answer (score 1):

All that information is stored in the `request` field of the [the RequestHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#request-handlers) instance. It can be accessed via `self.request` from within `RequestHandler` methods.

It's an instance of [`tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest). Information about browser, OS etc. will be found in the [`headers` field](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest.headers).

Example:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(self.request.headers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```